# Em uma galeria Wordpress, usar o atributo Alt das imagens como comentário html

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou desenvolvendo um tema Wordpress e estou com um problema. Em meu functions.php, uso o seguinte código que altera a composição do [gallery] e assim posso personalizar a galeria dos posts.

O código é o seguinte:

```
function __my_gallery_shortcode( $attr )
{
$post = get_post();

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    if ( ! empty( $attr['ids'] ) ) {
        // 'ids' is explicitly ordered, unless you specify otherwise.
        if ( empty( $attr['orderby'] ) )
            $attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';
        $attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
    }

    // Allow plugins/themes to override the default gallery template.
    $output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
    if ( $output != '' )
        return $output;

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post ? $post->ID : 0,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumb-portfolio',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => '',
        'link'       => 'file'
    ), $attr, 'gallery'));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $icontag = tag_escape($icontag);
    $valid_tags = wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' );
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $itemtag ] ) )
        $itemtag = 'dl';
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $captiontag ] ) )
        $captiontag = 'dd';
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $icontag ] ) )
        $icontag = 'dt';

    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
        $gallery_style = "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                float: {$float};
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: {$itemwidth}%;
            }
            #{$selector} img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
            /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
        </style>";
    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
    $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        if ( ! empty( $link ) && 'file' === $link )
            $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, false, false );
        elseif ( ! empty( $link ) && 'none' === $link )
            $image_output = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, false );
        else
            $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, true, false );

        $image_meta  = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );

        $orientation = '';
        if ( isset( $image_meta['height'], $image_meta['width'] ) )
            $orientation = ( $image_meta['height'] > $image_meta['width'] ) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon {$orientation}'>
                $image_output
            </{$icontag}>";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
                <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                </{$captiontag}>";
        }
        elseif ( $captiontag && ( 'dd' == $captiontag ) ) {
                       $output .= "
                               <{$captiontag} class='gallery-caption'>
                               </{$captiontag}>";
               }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '';
    }

    $output .= "
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
```

E ele me retorna um item da galeria assim:

```
<dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon">
            <a href="http://url-da-imagem.jpg">
                <img src="http://url-da-imagem.jpg" class="attachment-thumb-portfolio" alt="SOU O ALT SEU AMIGUINHO">
            </a>
        </dt>
        <dd class="gallery-caption">
        </dd>
</dl>
```

A questão é que preciso inserir o conteúdo do Alt da imagem como comentário html antes da tag . No caso seria isso:

```
<dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon">               
            <a href="http://url-da-imagem.jpg">
                <!--SOU O ALT SEU AMIGUINHO-->
                <img src="http://url-da-imagem.jpg" class="attachment-thumb-portfolio" alt="SOU O ALT SEU AMIGUINHO">
            </a>
        </dt>
        <dd class="gallery-caption">
        </dd>
</dl>
```

Pode parecer estranho, mas é isso mesmo. Sou grato a qualquer auxílio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Faltou você mostrar o filtro que chama sua função. Mas certamente é:

```
add_filter( 'post_gallery', '__my_gallery_shortcode', 10, 2 );

function __my_gallery_shortcode( $output, $attr ) {}
```

Repare que são `2` atributos na declaração do filtro (e prioridade `10`, default) e correspondem ao `$output, $attr`. Você estava tentando usar o `$attr` como primeiro parâmetro na função, e na verdade é o *output* e vem vazio.

**2)** Outra coisa é que tem um loop infinito na função, acontece no

```
$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
```

que volta a chamar seu `__my_gallery_shortcode()`. Esses `apply_filters` que tem no seu código podem ser removidos, ou então corre o risco de outros plugins filtrarem seu shortcode.

Para remover os filtros precisa do 2º parâmetro do *apply*. Por exemplo, converter isto:

```
$output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );
```

em

```
$output = $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div;
# e o primeiro ali encima:
$output = '';
```

**3)** Finalmente, o que precisa pode conseguir com `get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );` dentro do loop `foreach($attachments)`. Ajustei o `$image_output` para incluir o comentário dentro do `<a>`.

```
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {

    $imagem = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, false );
    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
    $img_perma = get_permalink( $id );
    $alt = '<!-- AQUI O ALT: ' . get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ) . ' -->';

    if ( ! empty( $link ) && 'file' === $link )
        $image_output = '<a href="' . $img_url . '">' . $alt . $imagem . '</a>';
    elseif ( ! empty( $link ) && 'none' === $link )
        $image_output = $alt . $imagem;
    else
        $image_output = '<a href="' . $img_perma . '">' . $alt . $imagem . '</a>';

    $image_meta  = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );

    $orientation = '';
    if ( isset( $image_meta['height'], $image_meta['width'] ) )
        $orientation = ( $image_meta['height'] > $image_meta['width'] ) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';

    $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
    $output .= "
        <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon {$orientation}'>
            $image_output
        </{$icontag}>";
```

PS: Tem um erro no `extract(shortcode_atts())`, coloque o link em branco:

```
'link'       => ''
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder @brasofilo. Entendi a parte 1) e 2), mas estou perdido na questão de inserir o "alt" como um comentário html igual no exemplo.

Comment: @Boni, puxa, falhei na explicação justo da 3ª parte :) Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: funfou seu código, mas ele saiu diferente do esperado.
`<!--SOU O ALT SEU AMIGUINHO--><dl class="gallery-item">        <dt class="gallery-icon"><a href="http://url-da-imagem.jpg"><img src="http://url-da-imagem.jpg" class="attachment-thumb-portfolio" alt="SOU O ALT SEU AMIGUINHO"></a></dt><dd class="gallery-caption"></dd></dl>`
O comentário deve vir dentro da tag <a> antes da <img>

Comment: não entendo, mas e o PHP como é que tá? Vc tentou manipular, tá bem claro ali a posição de cada coisa...

Comment: Sim, mas é no $image_output que está o segredo. O comentário deve vir dentro do <a>, antes do <img>. E pelo código que me passou, eu não consigo manipular o bendito $image_output

Comment: Entendi... O `wp_get_attachment_image` pega só o `<img>`, e `get_attachment_link($id)` pega só a URL, faz um novo $image_output com eles, eliminando o `if elseif else`.

Comment: Entendi, o problema é que, bem, sou um "analfabeto funcional do php". Já tinha reparado no $image_output antes de perguntar, mas não sei como montar um novo $image_output. Fiz uns testes é só dá erro de sintaxe, preciso que me ajude de novo @brasofilo hehe.

Comment: É, pra respeitar a seleção dos tipo de link na galeria ao construir o `$image_output` não tava muito simples... atualizei a resposta, já conferi e o output é correto.

Comment: Perfeito @brasofilo, muito obrigado!